# Google chrome: React Page does not open in google Chrome Browser

Tags: reactjs, google-chrome

I open a React page in Google chrome but does not open, still loading and Browser show Aw, snap! Can you suggest me What going Wrong.

**Image**

[image: chrome showing image]

Comment: Can you check the console to see if there are any errors?

Comment: dose not show any thing still loading loading

Comment: show your pages js code.

Comment: @NgSharma can u check whether it works in other browsers like firefox

Comment: @Nidhinkumar Yes It working on Firefox but not chrome.

Comment: @NgSharma can u check what is the version of chrome you are using as well

Answer (score 2):

The Aww Snap crush is a bug in chromium caused by different things:

**Low memory**

It is also possible that site contains lots of images or JavaScript which might force Chrome to run out of space on the device while loading the site.

I'd suggest you clear up some space on the device and reboot the device.

If it helps, try closing any unused application in background to save resources (CPU, RAM and disk space) and see if Chrome continues to crash.

**This vulnerability crashes browser tabs when encountering a link with a malformed URL in the HTML of a page.**

The bug crashes the browser without the user taking any direct action other than loading the affected page.

This vulnerability occurs because of Chrome's habit of prefetching page data, such as performing DNS lookups on domain names in links on a page, in a preemptive attempt to speed up future loads. Chrome will try and work out which link on a site you're likely to click on next and then pre-load in the background.

**Possible fix is disabling pre-fetching**

Go to Settings >> Privacy >> Use a prediction service to load pages more quickly >> Uncheck box.

1. Another possible cause is a corrupt profile.

You can create a new profile, but if you do, custom data won't be available by default. This includes bookmarks, extensions and settings that you may have changed in Chrome.

Comment: Okay I Will follow your step.

Comment: I do not know what the problem in chrome, anyway I am using fox is work perfectly .